# DataTable global filtering not working as expected when using columns templates

Tags: datatable, primeng

i'm trying using global filtering width PrimeNG dataTable template columns, but filter behave weird and not working as expected

```html
Global filter: <input #gb pInputText type="text">
<hr>
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [globalFilter]="gb">
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin">
      <template let-col let-car="rowData" pTemplate="body">
           {{car[col.field]}}
        </template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year">
      <template let-col let-car="rowData" pTemplate="body">
          {{car[col.field]}}
        </template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Brand">
      <template let-col let-car="rowData" pTemplate="body">
          {{car[col.field]}}
        </template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="color" header="Color">
        <template let-col let-car="rowData" pTemplate="body">
          {{car[col.field]}}
        </template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I made [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DW7Tun?p=preview) to demonstrate the issue

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok we had the same problem. And after an hour of endless google searching. We noticed we hadn't the latest version. Simply by updating to 1.1.4, the problem was solved.

Comment: You right, I just update [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iGmyz0?p=preview) PrimeNG version to 1.1.4, and it's filtering as expected